# How to add <br> in string with substr()

Tags: php, html, substring, substr, strlen

For the following code :

```html
<?php
$word = 'SEKISUI';

// echo substr($word,0,-6)."<br>";
$length = (strlen($word)+1)-14;
$urut = 0;
  for($i=$length;$i<1;$i++){
    echo substr($word,$urut,$i).'<br>';
//    echo $urut."-".$i."-".'<br>'; // Check Value
    $urut++;
  }

?>
```

Result :

```html
S
E
K
I
S
U
```

why the letter "i" doesn't appear?
what is wrong with my code?
The result should look like:

```html
S
E
K
I
S
U
I
```

Thank you for your attention...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you NEED to use a 'for loop', but there is a better way to split a string into single characters.

Once you have the array you can do any operation to it, also join() the items in the array with a "\< br>" separator.

Try the following:

```
$word = 'SEKISUI';
$result = str_split($word);
$altogether = join("<br>",$result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you like the subtracting the length and not deal with positive numbers as much as possible.

In the syntax of `substr(string,start,length)`,

> Optional. Specifies the length of the returned string. Default is to
>   the end of the string. A positive number - The length to be returned
>   from the start parameter Negative number - The length to be returned
>   from the end of the string

So essentially your pointer on the end character is nevel counted.
if you run `echo substr($word,0,-1)."<br>";`, you will not get the end character as it is place of the start for the negative `substr`.
However, changing the `substr` length to `1` will give a valid string and `not null` or `empty string`

```
$word = 'SEKISUI';

// echo substr($word,0,-6)."<br>";
$length = (strlen($word)+1)-14;
$urut = 0;
  for($i=$length;$i<1;$i++){
    echo substr($word,$urut,1).'<br>';
//    echo $urut."-".$i."-".'<br>'; // Check Value
    $urut++;
  }
```

However, I would prefer this approach, as this is much simpler.

```
$word = 'SEKISUI';

//echo substr($word,1,1)."<br>";
$length = strlen($word);
$urut = 0;
for($i = $urut; $i <= $length; $i++){
  echo substr($word,$i,1).'<br>';
}
```